# I need help purchasing materials for a arduino fpv quadcopter

Tags: arduino-uno

I am an absolute noob in FPV quadcopters and quads in general. My aim is to create a simple quadcopter with a live video transmission. Based on my research I need:

- 4 rotors
- 4 Props
- 4 Electronic Speed Controllers
- Camera Kit
- Lipo battery
- Power Distribution Board
- Accel. and Gyro
- Arduino UNO
- Receiver Kit

Am I missing anything? and how would you wire it?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't see what this has to do with Arduino's so I have voted to close it.  To be honest if you have to ask what parts you need then maybe you should consider if it would be safe for you to build one.  Maybe you should look at kits to get more familiar with the subject.

Comment: Transmitter, battery charger, display, a smaller arduino that the UNO (e.g. Pro Mini), wire-connectors (especially for connecting to the battery).

Comment: This is not a practical approach.  If you want to experiment with applications such as FPV, you should be using on off-the-shelf flight stabilization computer and radio link, the engineering of both of which has moved far beyond Arduino experiments.  If your goal is instead to build the flight computer, for safety reasons you should be experimenting on a platform far smaller and lighter than one that can lift an Uno.  There was a point a few years ago when Arduino based flight computers almost made sense, but today they are so crude and limited compared to the options actually in use.

Comment: I wanted to create one from scratch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**These are my suggestions.**

You don't need the following:

- Accel. (a gyro is enough)

---

You are missing the following:

- You need 2 sets of receiver/transmitter. One of them is for the controller, the other one, for video.
- You also need a screen or PFV goggles to display the received video.
- You need a frame.

---

Here is my suggestions for a couple of your parts.

- Buy a DIY Flame Wheel Kit. They should include : motors, ESCs, props and the frame itself.
- Get a GoPro Hero (original) for your camera. They're cheap and should give you good enough quality for a DIY quadcopter build.
- Use and Arduino Pro Mini, they are smaller. Note that you need an external FTDI programmer for it.
- Use at least a 3S lipo.

Comment: A MEMS gyro is not enough. They drift over time (derivative), so you need an accelerometer, to know which way is down.

Comment: @Gerben - actually that is untrue.  The goal of the gyro is not to consistently orient the vehicle, but to slow its uncommanded rotation (or in this case multi-axis tumbling) to the point where a human pilot can achieve desired oritentation by command inputs based on visual observation.  Systems which also include accelerometers are more friendly to beginner pilots as they can also be self orienting, but that is only a feature that became common in the past few years.

Comment: I am using a display instead of goggles. The receiver kit comes with a transmitter and remote controller (a.k.a transmitter). The frame I was planning to use wood.